# JSON Deserialisation issue with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, resttemplate

Bleow is the json which has to be converted into object by using Spring Rest Template.

```
{"userResponse": {
   "build": 1,
   "code": 400,
   "status": "Failed",
   "validationErrors":    [
            {
         "fieldName": "userId",
         "message": "User Id is NOT in valid format"
      },
            {
         "fieldName": "password",
         "message": "Password cannot be less than 8 characters"
      }
   ]
}}
```

The issue is here when list of elements for validationErrors are part of the response.

Below is the spring rest template configuration.

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">   
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" >          
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" /> 
            </bean>             
        </list>
    </property>   
</bean>
```

Below is the code for calling postForObject.

`restTemplate.postForObject( "ServiceUrl",  "userinput", Registration.class );`

Below is the error throwing while calling the service.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
```

Please provide some input to resolve the issue.

Comment: What does your `Registration` class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your "userinput" needs to be a JSON formatted string and it's not, so the service you're trying to contact is probably replying with "bad request" because you aren't sending a valid JSON.

The [API documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object...%29) tells you about how you need to format your parameters for that method. You should make sure you're posting a properly formatted JSON (I'd recommend using a java object, and serializing that using Jackson like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectWriter normalWriter = mapper.writer();
String jsonString = normalWriter.writeValueAsString(objectToMakeJson);
```

Comment: I am able to send the request to service with postForObject Method. "userinput" is the request object."ServiceUrl is the actual URL". But the problem is when the response contains the List of objects as specified in sample JSON is NOT deserializing into Object. Note: its deserializing if the response doesn't contain list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your `"userinput"` should be valid JSON ( eg. `{"userinput" : {"dataKey" : "dataValue"}}` ). Also it's not clear if `"ServiceUrl"` is a placeholder for an actual URL in the snippet you provided, make sure that URL is valid as well.